# how to set the default year selected as our current year today?

Tags: jquery

I have a datepicker of jquery, but the problem is, the year being displayed is the beginning of what i set, 1940, so how to set the currently selected year as our year to day ,2011 ?

here's my code

```
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({changeYear: true,changeMonth: true,yearRange:'1940:2010'});
})
```

Comment: did you try `defaultDate` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It has [default date](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) option:

```
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

this is what said on jQuery site:

*Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.*